# Laravel undefined variable in view, Laravel 5.2 using AdminLTE

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting an error in laravel 5.2 
when I access it using the **storeMessage function** on my Controller

This is my **ERROR STATEMENT**:

> ErrorException in 6e12af76911d23528f6e0ea587ccab13391eacf9.php line 37:
>   Undefined variable: thisPage (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\beasiswa\resources\views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\beasiswa\resources\views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\beasiswa\resources\views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php)

And this is my code:
**View Code**

```html
<?php $thisPage = "jenisbeasiswa"; ?>

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('htmlheader_title')
 Portal Beasiswa
@endsection

@section('contentheader_title')
Broadcast Beasiswa via Telegram Messenger
@endsection

@section('main-content')
 <form action="{{ url('/send-message') }}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your query" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

and this is my **Controller Code**:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Telegram\Bot\FileUpload\InputFile;
use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;

class TelegramBotController extends Controller
{
    public function updatedActivity()
    {
        $activity = Telegram::getUpdates();
        dd($activity);
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {
        return view('beasiswa.telegram');
    }
    
    public function storeMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        $text = "[HEADLINE] Informasi Portal Beasiswa\n"
            . "<b>Email Address: </b>\n"
            . "$request->email\n"
            . "<b>Message: </b>\n"
            . $request->message;

        Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => env('TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_ID', ''),
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'text' => $text
        ]);
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your **view** code please

Comment: From Review: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51627624/edit) your question and post the error as text. Do not post is as a comment to your own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `sidebar.blade.php` is referring to the `$thisPage` variable (which is declared at the top of your view code). My guess is, you are including the sidebar in the `layouts.app` template. But as you extend your `layouts.app` the `$thisPage` variable will get rendered in the sidebar first before the declaration comes in your view code. And thus, it will be undefined in the Sidebar.

So, you should try another approach. Why do you even want to set the `$thisPage` variable? Maybe you can pass it in from the controller?